# I can't wrap my head around Tampermonkey script update mecanics

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Here is the script i've been writing

```html
// ==UserScript==
// @name         NEW USERSCRIPT
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// @updateURL    https://pastebin.com/raw/BiEtDTqS
// @downloadURL  https://pastebin.com/raw/BiEtDTqS
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

    alert("Yes");

})();
```

I'm trying to make it update based on the https://pastebin.com/raw/BiEtDTqS URL, yet it won't change

I checked in the parameters and the update url thing is effectively checked

Comment: The browser is caching the response. Try to add `?foo=bar` to the URL.

Comment: Does not seem to work. Btw i added a "#.user.js" string at the end of my url to ensure it to be taken into account by tampermonkey

Comment: Then it should look like `https://pastebin.com/raw/BiEtDTqS?foo=.user.js`

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: btw i dont really care about using pastebin or not, im just looking for a free way to allow updates to my userscripts

Comment: Try a different site, for example use a `gist` on github.

Comment: cant wrap my head around github either. any way to get the desired url update link from a gist paste ?

Comment: Yeah, press the `Raw` button in UI and append `?foo=.user.js` to the new URL.